# URL overwritten by apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, html5-appcache

I have a CodeIgniter-based PHP website's login screen on this local URL: http://pos-pizza-app.dev/login

I have a `.htaccess` file that redirects all requests to CodeIgniter's `index.php`.

I have a `login.appcache` file in the project root.

When I call http://pos-pizza-app.dev/login, Apache serves `login.appcache` instead of redirecting to `index.php` (the request doesn't reach `index.php`). Server is latest XAMPP on Windows.

For all other URLs the redirect works, and it also works if I remove the `login.appcache` file.

But I need the file there, so I want to understand why Apache serves it instead of the login page and prevent it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your html (view source) for `<html manifest="login.appcache">`

more info
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Comment: Yes, it does start with `<html manifest="/login.appcache" type="text/cache-manifest">`. But why does it overrule the web server settings? You are probably pointing in the right direction, but the linked page didn't answer this question.

Comment: It is a cache sistem. you can disable in .htaccess or in php
check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797573/prevent-apache-to-cache-html5-manifest) for more details how to disable